# Retrieve date from corrupted datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have a timeseries dataframe which has over 11000 observations. Unfortunately the datetime column got corrupted when stored in .csv format. The date portion (Y/M/D) went missing and I am left with only the time as shown below in the first 50 observations of the dataframe.

I know that the same values in the sequence of left out Time portion of the corrupted date_time column correspond to a specific date. For example all observations with the date_time value "10:27.9" correspond to a specific date and all observations with the value "45:05.8" correspond to some other date (here previous date).

Given this, how can I get the original datetime column (in Y/M/D H:M:S format) assuming the first set of rows belong to 15th April, 2021, the 2nd set to 14th Apr, 2021, so on., for each previous day passed. As I am not sure what is 10:27.9 is (I guess it is in S:M:H format), it does not matter if I get any values for the H:M:S portion as long as I have correct date.

Appreciate inputs.

```
    D       Date_Time
0   349     10:27.9
1   20      10:27.9
2   66      10:27.9
3   29      10:27.9
4   14      10:27.9
5   112     10:27.9
6   104     10:27.9
7   22      10:27.9
8   135     10:27.9
9   33      10:27.9
10  81      10:27.9
11  53      10:27.9
12  2       10:27.9
13  9       10:27.9
14  18      10:27.9
15  24      10:27.9
16  50      10:27.9
17  1       10:27.9
18  28      10:27.9
19  4       10:27.9
20  9       10:27.9
21  11      10:27.9
22  5       10:27.9
23  1       10:27.9
24  0       10:27.9
25  3       10:27.9
26  0       10:27.9
27  0       10:27.9
28  0       10:27.9
29  0       10:27.9
30  0       10:27.9
31  0       10:27.9
32  0       10:27.9
33  0       10:27.9
34  2       10:27.9
35  0       10:27.9
36  278     45:05.8
37  22      45:05.8
38  38      45:05.8
39  25      45:05.8
40  18      45:05.8
41  104     45:05.8
42  67      45:05.8
43  24      45:05.8
44  120     45:05.8
45  29      45:05.8
46  73      45:05.8
47  51      45:05.8
48  3       45:05.8
49  8       45:05.8
50  18      45:05.8
```

Comment: but what does time `45:05.8` mean? `mm:ss` with no hour?

Comment: @tdy I guess it is Second: Minutes: Hours. Actually, iIt does not matter. If I get this time portion with any random values, example:10:10:10, I am Ok.

Comment: @Srinivas Actually it does matter... if you know what the corrupted format is, you can convert it properly.

Comment: @JeffC, I understand what you say. SInce my rest of data wrangling is based on just the date, I have mentioned it does not matter. However, my guess is the corrupted format is in S:M:H format; but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a reverse [**`date_range()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) starting at 2021-04-15 and then [**`map()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the current `Date_Time` values.

Note that this does not preserve the times, but that was acceptable if I understood the comments correctly.

```py
keys = df.Date_Time.unique()
values = pd.date_range('2021-04-15', periods=keys.size, freq='-1D')
mapping = dict(zip(keys, values))

df.Date_Time = df.Date_Time.map(mapping)

#       D  Date_Time
# 0   349 2021-04-15
# 1    20 2021-04-15
# 2    66 2021-04-15
# ...
# 48    3 2021-04-14
# 49    8 2021-04-14
# 50   18 2021-04-14
```

Comment: thanks for the input. But I believe this amounts to manually assigning values for 300+ sets; I hope there shall be a more efficient way.

Comment: Are you saying every block of dates is 1 day earlier? First block Apr 15, second block Apr 14, third block Apr 13, etc? Otherwise I don't see how you can extrapolate the dates automatically.

Comment: Yes. correct. Every consecutive block corresponds to a day earlier.

Comment: @Srinivas Ok try the update. It maps the reverse `date_range()` automatically.